# Cannot install Ionic through npm

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I have been now trying to install Ionic framework through npm but with no success.
I am trying the usual command,

`npm install -g ionic`

I already have cordova installed. 
I have updated my npm version to be the latest and also tried,

`npm cache clean`

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

But I am still getting the following errors:

[image: This is what I get]

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Run cmd **as administrator** and see if you have compatible versions of Node and NPM installed.

Comment: I have already answered this question, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Answer (score 2):

Try using latest version of node and npm.
. + try using npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/.. May be you around a firewall