# installing ionic npm ERR! tar.unpack error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

while installing ionic npm install -g ionic getting error.

[image]

Have tried : -

1. npm cache clean 2. run the cli by administrator 3. restarted the system but error remain same.

Badly stocked.

Comment: Are you sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. But by set https_proxy command have set the required proxy. still same error. Is there any alternative to install the ionic by .exe format.

Comment: strange. Did you also set the http-proxy  besides the https-proxy? Be sure that the android-sdk manager is closed (if you are using it). I guess there is no download for ionic without npm.

Comment: yes. every thing closed. Have cleared that folder user -> Temp folder also. can i change the location user -> Temp to some other location. There might be chance that it blocked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having same problem on Windows 8 (64 bit)

Solution:

Don't forget to install other dependencies before installing ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

1) Uninstall Node from Control Panel

2) Restart PC

3) Download (MSI Installer) older version of Node from    http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/  or 64bit http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/

4) Install Node version 0.10.38

5) npm install -g cordova

6) npm install -g ionic

Done!

Answer (score 0):

it is not nessesary to uninstall node...

just remove the old npm ionic folder

```
...AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
```

and try again

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the answers provided did not work. I got around this problem by installing cordova and ionic at the same time.

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

If proxy is preventing this, other things to try are setting the proxy, making http request and disabling strict-ssl. An example of setting proxy is

```
npm config set proxy=http://username:password@domain:port/
```

To make http request only change the config

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

To disable strict-ssl

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

Also, if you wanted to view the default list of configs type

```
npm config ls -l
```

This will also show what configurations have been overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Node.js and install freshly after done installation run the following command

npm install -g ionic cordova

That's it.