# Error install ionic cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

So, I'm trying to install ionic cordova in my computer, but don't have sucess. Can anybody help me, please?

```
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program Files\n
node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
```

I tried do a lot of things: execute as adm, reinstall.
My system is 64-bit 
and this is my path:

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Cássia\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Comment: I am not familiar with ionic cordova but IMO network npm ERR should be the keyword you may want to search.

Comment: I am not either, I am gettiing started. i found a command npm set value but I I don t know how I.set this

Comment: Like the error says: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Already answered and explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the path that you have provided, it still has the path for npm missing. I recommend you to uninstall the node from control panel, restart your device and install the correct version of node. For me, `node version 5.3.0` is working as well. However, installing `Node version 0.10.38` may do the trick for you.
My path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;
C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\office\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```