# Ionic installation error in windows 10

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Ionic is not installing in my windows 10.When I try to install ionic it says 
:

```
"npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.4.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-12064-1146f371\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: af493d5df4688d917d778b0934d1739b9be6efe6
npm ERR! Actual:   5ad3456db7c10c1c57e18c294f2815840b9ce990
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm ERR!"
```

These are the paths in my system environment variable:

```
    C:\app\zahid\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
    C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Android\sdk\tools;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Comment: can you show your path from environment variable?

Comment: I have added the paths. @Alex Rumba Nicked.

Comment: seeing the path that you have provided i cannot see the path to npm. I recommend you to uninstall the node from control panel, restart your device and install the correct version of node. For me, node version 5.3.0 is working as well. your path should contain C:\Users\office\AppData\Roaming\npm; See if this helps.

Comment: It was in my user variables. I have also paste it in my system variables but that doesn't work either. Can you suggest which version of node should i use for my windows 10..

Comment: can you check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051945/error-install-ionic-cordova/35400975#35400975

Comment: Yes, that helped me. I went to http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/ link and downloaded the older version then tried to install ionic.Though there are some warning and error but is runs.. thank you for your help.. :)

Comment: you could have upvoted if the answer helped you :P glad i could be of some help :)

Comment: I am new here..so I don't know things very well... I tried to upvote but it says  something about reputation... sorry  for that.....

Comment: your rep is not enough right now :) glad to have you in stackoverflow. Learning and teaching process just started for you. Have fun