# Ionic is Not Installing on Windows 7 - Getting Many Errors

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, installation, ionic-framework

I am  getting this error while i am trying to install Ionic

```
$ npm install ionic cordova -g
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ansi-regex\2.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ansi-regex\2.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ansi-regex\2.0.0\package.tgz
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ansi-regex\2.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\ansi-regex\2.0.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\delayed-stream\0.0.5\package.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "cordova" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! syscall scandir

npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\Sridhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-installed']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -4094,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'scandir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\Sridhar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\read-installed' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sridhar\npm-debug.log
```

Please help me to install Ionic

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the below steps to install ionic.

**IONIC Setup**

Setup Environment (Installations)

1. Install Node.js

   a. http://nodejs.org/download/
2. install ionic framework

   a. $ npm install -g cordova ionic
3. install android SDK and set environment variables

   a. Set following environment variable

   b. set ANDROID_HOME=C:\\android-sdk-windows

**Install Android Target 19 (follow following steps)**

1. Open the SDK Manager (typing android into the terminal, assuming it's in your file path)
2. Selected box next to Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
3. Clicked button Install 8 packages

**Install ant using CMD window**

1. npm Install  -g ant

   a. Add following path in environment variables (PATH):
   C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant\ant\bin

**Once you setup the ionic environment. 
Create the basic application for testing.**

1. Open node.js command prompt
2. ionic start myApp tabs
3. cd myApp
4. ionic serve (it will open the application in browser)
5. ionic platform add android (replace ios with android if you want to add iOS platform)
6. ionic build android  (replace ios with android if you want to build in iOS platform)
7. ionic emulate android android  (replace ios with android if you want to emulate iOS platform)

**NOTE:** If ERR occurs, follow below link:
[installing ionic npm ERR! tar.unpack error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004466/installing-ionic-npm-err-tar-unpack-error/31124491#31124491)

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the right installation sequence ?

***Install or update Node.js***

Download the most recent version of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). If you are running an older version of Node, make sure to update it because older versions had issues with npm.

As with the other commands, `nodejs` should now function in `cmd.exe` but just to be careful, add the full path to the `bin` folder in Node to your `PATH`, which will look something like `C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin`

***Install Cordova***

Open a new `cmd.exe` window, and run:

```
$ npm install -g cordova
```

***Install Ionic***

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

Find the official installation [doc](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and [this](http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/) too for more.